# Android calendar view displays two calendar using caldroid

Tags: android, caldroid

I have a Calendar View in my activity, am using Caldroid library for displaying events. I am facing an issue that, for a calendar view it displays two calendar in my activity.

```
calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.cvCalendar);


    final CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.cvCalendar, caldroidFragment);
    t.commit();
```

[Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ00r.png)

The layout file is shown below: `

```
<RelativeLayout><CalendarView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cvCalendar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Also am getting a warning in logcat, which is shown below

```
12-15 13:26:22.291 1019-1057/? W/PackageManager: Code path for pkg : com.example.android1.calender changing from /data/app/com.example.android1.calender-29.apk to /data/app/com.example.android1.calender-30.apk
12-15 13:26:22.291 1019-1057/? W/PackageManager: Resource path for pkg : com.example.android1.calender changing from /data/app/com.example.android1.calender-29.apk to /data/app/com.example.android1.calender-30.apk
12-15 13:26:22.481 1019-1057/? W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL to package com.example.android1.calender (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x48be46)
12-15 13:26:26.085 31128-31128/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.example.android1.calender [ userId:0 | appId:10184 ]
12-15 13:26:54.516 1019-1044/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{42e2f170 u0 com.example.android1.calender/.register t21}: app died, no saved state
12-15 13:26:56.418 1019-1057/? W/PackageManager: Code path for pkg : com.example.android1.calender changing from /data/app/com.example.android1.calender-30.apk to /data/app/com.example.android1.calender-31.apk
12-15 13:26:56.418 1019-1057/? W/PackageManager: Resource path for pkg : com.example.android1.calender changing from /data/app/com.example.android1.calender-30.apk to /data/app/com.example.android1.calender-31.apk
12-15 13:26:56.668 1019-1057/? W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL to package com.example.android1.calender (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x48be46)
12-15 13:26:59.951 31755-31755/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.example.android1.calender [ userId:0 | appId:10184 ]
```

Comment: Post your layout file here.

Comment: You have taken a calendarView and also caldroidFragment,remove one of them as per requirement.

Comment: @JIGAR: even I have tried that, but still it shows two calendar

Comment: @Krishna how u resolved i m also getting same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using default [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) layout in your xml file. You should be using a simple linear layout instead. Try changing CalendarView in your xml layout to a simple linear layout as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cvCalendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tried changing the layout but the issue is still there